# update(edit) single input field php js

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

[image]

```
 <?php $count = 0; foreach ($jobsInputFields as $jobsInputField): ?>
    <form class="kt-form kt-form--label-right w-100" id="groupFormAddInputField">
     <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
     <input name="count" hidden type="text" value="<?=$count?>"/>
     <div class="form-group form-group-sm row">
         <input name="extraInputFieldId<?=$count?>" hidden type="text" value="<?=$jobsInputField->id?>"/>
         <label name="extraField" class="col-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm"><?=$jobsInputField->extra_field?></label>
     <div class="col-7">
         <div class="kt-input-icon">
            <input value="<?=$jobsInputField->value?>" name="value<?=$count?>" type="text" style="padding-right:30px;" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Indtast værdi">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger" id="deleteExtraInputFieldJob"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="slet input felt"><i class="fad fa-trash"></i></span></button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-warning" id="editExtraInputFieldJob"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="redigere input felt"><i class="fad fa-edit"></i></span></button>
     </div>
  </div>             
  </form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I have this code, that has these input fields that get loop in. It should be possible to update on input at the time. But at the moment I'm only apple to update the first input field. Thats the resonse why i have put a counter in, to make the name unique for each input field. When you press the button "edit" it sendt the data to this script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#editExtraInputFieldJob').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        editNewJobInputField();
    })
</script>
```

This call the function editNewJobInputField();

```
function editNewJobInputField() {
console.log("edit called")
let count = $("input[name=count]").val();
console.log(count);
var body = {
  extraInputFieldId: $(`input[name=extraInputFieldId${count}]`).val(),
  value: $(`input[name=value${count}]`).val(),
};
console.log(body);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/php_components/db/update/job-field.php",
  data: body,
  beforeSend: function () {},
  success: function (data) {
  console.log(data);
    if (data.status !== 200) {
      $("#editAlert").show();
    } else {
      // $(".modal-edit").modal("hide");
      // location.reload();
    }
  }
  complete: function () {},
});
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique - a simple, basic rule, that you are violating with the content you are creating in a loop there.

Comment: `let count = $("input[name=count]").val();` - this will always get you the value of the _first_ matching element only.

Comment: `$('#editExtraInputFieldJob').click` will only handle inputs to the first button with that ID, out of the many that your loop might create. The reason is due to what CBroe said above. Try using classes, instead.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the answer but how do I archive my goal? I tried with classes instead of ID. But did not work out.

Comment: Well using the class should enable the button click to work on all the buttons. That's just the first step. But then you need to work out which are the fields related to that button which you need to get the values from. One way to do that is putting data-attributes on the button and the fields and matching them. Or using the DOM structure to find the nearest common parent, and then find the matching elements within that parent.

Comment: So I found a solution using the data-* attribute 
So to my button I added data-item="<?=$count?>" then in my script I added:
$('.editExtraInputFieldJob').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data('item');
            console.log(id);
            editNewJobInputField(id);
        })
so when calling the fn editNewJobInputField() I can now send my id as a parameter

Comment: That's great. If you found a solution please remember to add it as an Answer below with a full code example. No-one can search for it or vote for it when it's hidden in the comments. They also can't do it if you hide it in the original question - the answer is not part of the question! Right now, to the search engine, your question appears to still be un-answered. P.S. Please take the [tour] if you need a reminder of how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson thanks for letting me know :) I have posted it as an answer :D

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

So I Change my two button delete and edit to call  $('.editExtraInputFieldJob').click with a class instead of id. Then I added data-* attribute in the button

```
data-item="<?=$count?>"
```

So my button look like this know

```
<button type="submit" class="deleteExtraInputFieldJob" data-item="<?=$count?>"></button>
<button type="submit" class="editExtraInputFieldJob" data-item="<?=$count?>"</button>
```

In my script i'm apple to extract that info on the click event and send the id as a parameter to my fn editNewJobInputField(id).

```
$('.editExtraInputFieldJob').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).data('item');
        console.log(id);
        editNewJobInputField(id);
    })
```

First part of my editNewJobInputField

```
function editNewJobInputField(id) {
var body = {
extraInputFieldId: $(`input[name=extraInputFieldId${id}]`).val(),
value: $(`input[name=value${id}]`).val(),
};
```